# PyQt: splash screen while loading "heavy" libraries

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, pyqt

My PyQt application that uses `matplotlib` takes several seconds to load for the first time, even on a fast machine (the second load time is much shorter as the DLLs are kept in memory by Windows).

I'm wondering whether it's feasible to show a splash screen while the `matplotlib` library is being loaded. Where does the actual loading take place - is it when the `from` line is executed? If so, how can I make this line execute during the splash screen and still be able to use the module throughout the code?

A related dilemma is how to test this - can I ask Windows to load the DLLs for every execution and not cache them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, loading the module takes place at the line where the import statement is. If you create your `QApplication` and show your splash screen before that, you should be able to do what you want -- also you need  to call `QApplication.processEvents()` whenever you need the splash screen to update with a new message.

Comment: But how can I make the imports visible to top-level code? To make the imports delayed after a splash screen I should execute them inside a method/function - this causes the visibility problem

Comment: @eliben: You should have the 1st import of the "heavy" modules inside the function/method. Then the next time they are imported (from the top level of other modules) they are not loaded but just looked up in sys.modules, which is very fast.

Comment: What about importing ui files , cant get it working